# Second Callout fails in plot (code and datasets)

Tags: labeling, histograms

I have two large datasets to plot histograms and their PDFs. The code used is the following:

```
<< eNpop.dat;
Arand = Map[Sort, eNpop, {2}];
AArand = Cases[Arand, {_, _, _, _, _}, 2];
A1rand = N @ Flatten[Map[(#[[1]]) &, AArand]];
<< eFPSpop.dat;
Afps = Map[Sort, eFPSpop, {2}];
AAfps = Cases[Afps, {_, _, _, _, _}, 2];
A1fps = N @ Flatten[Map[(#[[1]]) &, AAfps]];
eϕ1rand = 
 FindDistribution[A1rand, TargetFunctions -> "Continuous", 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
A1fps = N @ Flatten[Map[(#[[1]]) &, AAfps]];
eϕ1fps = 
 FindDistribution[A1fps, TargetFunctions -> "Continuous", 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

Show[Legended[
  Histogram[
   <|"RAND" -> A1rand, "FPS" -> A1fps|>
   , {10}, "PDF", 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 350}, All}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
   ChartStyle -> 96, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None], Opacity[0.25]], 
   FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Probability"}], Placed[
   SwatchLegend[96, {"No stigmergy", "FPS"}], {0.9, 0.8}]],
 Plot[{Callout[PDF[eϕ1rand, x], 
    "FrechetDistribution (α=0.9, β=65.3, μ=-6.7)", \
{150, 0.0075}, 40, CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"],
   PDF[eϕ1fps, x]
   }, {x, 0, 350}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All], 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

The datasets `eNpop.dat`and `eFPSpop.dat` can be downloaded from

[(the two data sets)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8l1au2vtu1vz0xv/datasets.zip?dl=0)

The code above it works fine with the one `Callout`but it does not work if I try to put a second `Callout`for the second PDF function.

How could I set the two `Callouts`in the same plot?

Besides, I want to include this figure in a publication. How could I improve it?. I have been testing Histogram options with no clear better results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments to your previous question on this topic, you need to upgrade from `v11.0.0` to `v11.0.1`

```
$Version

(*  "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"  *)

<< /Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/datasets/eNpop.dat;

<< /Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/datasets/eFPSpop.dat;

Arand = Map[Sort, eNpop, {2}];
AArand = Cases[Arand, {_, _, _, _, _}, 2];
A1rand = N@Flatten[Map[(#[[1]]) &, AArand]];
Afps = Map[Sort, eFPSpop, {2}];
AAfps = Cases[Afps, {_, _, _, _, _}, 2];
A1fps = N@Flatten[Map[(#[[1]]) &, AAfps]];
eϕ1rand = 
  FindDistribution[A1rand, TargetFunctions -> "Continuous", 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
A1fps = N@Flatten[Map[(#[[1]]) &, AAfps]];
eϕ1fps = 
  FindDistribution[A1fps, TargetFunctions -> "Continuous", 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
```

Note that your [`Callout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) had the wrong parameters for the [`FrechetDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrechetDistribution.html)

```
Show[
 Legended[
  Histogram[<|"RAND" -> A1rand, "FPS" -> A1fps|>, {10}, "PDF",
   PlotRange -> {{0, 350}, All},
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
   ChartStyle -> 96,
   ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None], Opacity[0.25]],
   FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Probability"}], 
  Placed[LineLegend[96, {"No stigmergy", "FPS"}], {0.9, 0.85}]],
 Plot[{
   Callout[PDF[eϕ1rand, x],
    StringForm["FrechetDistribution (α=`1`, β=`2`, μ=`3`)",
     Sequence @@ (NumberForm[#, {3, 1}] & /@ eϕ1rand)],
    {150, 0.007}, 50,
    CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"],
   Callout[PDF[eϕ1fps, x], StringReplace[ToString[eϕ1fps],
     {"{Cauchy" -> "\n{Cauchy", "Inverse" -> "\nInverse"}],
    {190, 0.01}, 65,
    CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"]},
  {x, 0, 350},
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  PlotRange -> All],
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have upgraded Mathematica to 11.0.1 version and it works. I would like this figure to look prettier because I want to include it in a publication. How could I improve it?. I have been testing Histogram options with no clear better results. (I am going to add this part in the question). Regards.

Comment: @user1993416 - Rapidly accepting an answer and adding to the question are counterproductive. An accepted answer is less likely to get further attention. Also, "How could I improve it?" is vague/subjective and requires any reader to try and guess what you would consider to be an improvement. You could start by reformatting the `Callout` for the `MixtureDistribution`. You should be able to do that using the other one as an example and referring to the documentation. Why is the left axis labeled "Probability" when you are plotting "Probability Density"?